# WSO2 API Manager 4.2.0 user registration - how to notify admin user pending approval task?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

**Problem**

We are trying to configure WSO2 API Manager 4.2.0 user registration workflow with administrator approval.
Users can create a new account using the registration form. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to notify the admin user that a user approval task is pending.

**Steps**

I have configured API-M 4.2.0 for adding a workflow to the user self signup using the documentation:
[adding-a-user-signup-workflow](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/customizations/adding-a-user-signup-workflow/)

This works in that;

- a user can sign up for a new account
- the account request must be accepted by an admin before the user can successfully log in.

How does the administrator know there are pending tasks without logging into the admin console? Is there a way to automatically notify the administrator?

**Update #1**
After suggestion below, I have looked at the IS docs and found

[configure-the-notification-management-framework](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/tenants/user-operation-notifications/#configure-the-notification-management-framework)

This looks ideal - generating email notifications for all user actions (inluding adding accounts, so we could get notifications for sign ups requiring approval).

I tried this confirguarion, however, it didnt work with error.

`{org.wso2.carbon.identity.notification.mgt.email.EmailSendingModule} - Error while sending email notification to address myemailaddress@gmail.com on event userOperation org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the mailto:myemailaddress@gmail.com URL`

I suspect this may be because we are using the default API-M Resident Key Manager rather than the full Identity Server product?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to configure it completely but I guess you'd have to set-up e-mail notifications in the API-Manager.

I'd recommend the following guides/docs:

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-versioning/enabling-notifications/
This is for notifying customers about API changes. In Step 4 there is an example of how to enable notifications. Note the "Type" in the example.

https://medium.com/@idpremadasa/enabling-email-notifications-in-wso2-api-manager-with-your-gmail-account-1ca43f33e774 (Older version of API-Manager)

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/config-catalog/#enable-notifications

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/config-catalog/#multi-tenancy-configurations

The WSO2 API-Manager uses internally the WSO2 IdentityServer. Sometimes the DOCS of WSO2 IS can be helpful in understanding the configuration options:
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.0.0/guides/identity-lifecycles/self-registration-workflow/

Comment: As per your suggestion, I have looked at the IS docs and found [configure-the-notification-management-framework](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/tenants/user-operation-notifications/#configure-the-notification-management-framework) which looked exactly what I was looking for - generating email notifications for all user actions (so we could get notifications for sign ups requiring approval). I tried this confirguarion, however, it didnt work with error. Updated question with errors.

Answer (score 0):

With API-M 4.2.0 configured with default API-M Resident Key Manager (rather than Identity Server) it is not possible to enable email notifications for pending user workflow actions (e.g. self registration).

Instead, we wrote a bash script to periodically poll the API-M admin API - see [WSO2 API Manager - Admin (v4)](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/product-apis/admin-apis/admin-v4/admin-v4/#tag/Workflow-(Collection)) - to check for pending workflow tasks.

The bash script can send an email alert if pending workflow tasks are found, or can log the information to a file (which can be monitored and alerts generated).